# WCF accessing FaultException details from IErrorHandler.ProvideFault in the client

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

I am trying to attach additional information to a `FaultException` for a `WCF` service, and then access it in the client.  I am using the `IErrorHandler` `ProvideFault` method as my service has many methods that it exposes and I want to define the error handling logic in one place.

I have defined a data class `CoreFault`:

```
[DataContract]
public class CoreFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And implemented the `IErrorHandler` interface to return a strongly typed `FaultException`:

```
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message message)
    {
        var faultException = new FaultException<CoreFault>(
            new CoreFault
            {
                Foo = "Bar"
            },
            "An error occurred",
            null);

        var fault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();

        message = Message.CreateMessage(
            version,
            fault,
            faultException.Action);
    }
}
```

My service is configured in code:

```
public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
{
    (config.Description.Behaviors[0] as ServiceBehaviorAttribute).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
    config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ErrorHandlingBehaviour());
}
```

I have breakpointed the code after creating the message, and it shows the following XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header/>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-GB">An error occurred</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <CoreFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EmployerPortal.Models.Faults">
                    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
                </CoreFault>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But in my client, the error that is thrown is `FaultException` and not `FaultException<CoreFault>`, and the extra information is lost.

```
try
{
    // Call service here
    ...
}
catch (FaultException<CoreFault> e)
{
    throw;
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    // This line is hit
    throw;
}
```

How can I pass `Foo` to the client, so that it can access it when it handles the exception?